# Many students take courses to help with the_________of their knowledge

Tags: word-form

> Many students take courses to help with the_________of their knowledge

This is a problem in my teacher's assignment, the problem is to fill in the correct form of the word in the blank.

I need to fill in the correct form of the word "broad", I thought of the answer "broadness" but got the incorrect answer. Can you please explain why the answer is wrong and what is the correct answer?

Comment: Hint: "broad" is an adjective, e.g., a *broad* highway. Since the definite article precedes the word, it must be a noun, in this particular phrase. Look up "broad" and find a noun form.

Answer (score 1):

The noun most closely related to "broad" is **breadth.**